# Rails cancan issue with before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I recently integrated cancan (1.6.9) into my Rails (3.2.10) project for authorization, and I'm having an issue with manually loading a resource in a before_filter.  Here's a brief description of my scenario.

In config/routes.rb, I have the following entries...

```
resources :users
match '/profile', :to => 'users#show'
```

Here's what my users_controller.rb looks like...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_show_resource, :only => :show
  load_and_authorize_resource
  ...
  def show
  end
  ...
  private

    def load_show_resource
      @user = params[:id] ? User.find(params[:id]) : current_user
    end
end
```

If my current_user's id is 1, this code will let me access localhost:3000/users/1 but not localhost:3000/profile.

The entry in my cancan ability.rb class that's blocking this access is seen below - it's the cannot section.  If I comment out the cannot entry, both urls work.

```
...
can [:show, :update], User, :id => user.id
cannot [:show, :update, :destroy], User do |u|
  u.site_id != user.site_id
end
....
```

Shouldn't cancan use the resource that's being manually loaded in the before_filter for the show action regardless of whether or not params[:id] is present?

Interestingly enough, if I modify my users controller (see below) to use skip_load_and_authorize_resource :only => :show and manually calling authorize! in the show action, both urls work.  Also, if I remove cancan altogether both urls work.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  skip_load_and_authorize_resource :only => :show
  ...
  def show
    @user = params[:id] ? User.find(params[:id]) : current_user
authorize! :show, @user
  end
  ...
  private

    def load_show_resource
      @user = params[:id] ? User.find(params[:id]) : current_user
    end
end
```

So, my question is why does what's explained in the Override loading in the [cancan documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions), not work in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you try to use the `before_filter` with the `skip_load_and_authorize_resource` workflow?

Answer (score 0):

```
# controller

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource, :except => :show
  # skip_load_and_authorize_resource :only => :show
  ...
  def show
    @user = params[:id] ? User.find(params[:id]) : current_user
    authorize! :show, @user
  end
  ...
end

# ability.rb

can [:show, :update, :destroy], User do |u|
  u.id == user.id && u.site_id == user.site_id
end
```